# What is this piece inside the spigot supply hole, and what is it used for?

Tags: plumbing, water, leak

I'm watching videos online describing how to fix a leaky Delta kitchen faucet.  As I'm following the instructions I encounter an odd hitch.  Where, according to the video, there should be an empty and clear spigot supply hole, mines has this weird object I'm not exactly sure what it does.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what this part does, and is it needed to stay in the spigot supply hole are entirely optional to keep out? Is it possible this ist he source of the leaks?

With the piece in question:
[image]

Without the piece in question:
[image]

Comment: It looks like the diverter valve for the spray hose. When you turn on the spray hose, it causes a momentary loss of pressure in the faucet which causes the diverter valve to shut off the water to the faucet.

Comment: @BillOer So do you think it's necessary to keep it if I don't use the spray hose at all? Could it cause leaks, and should I keep it out, or is it okay to stay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed the spray hose diverter. I would not remove it, even if you don't normally use the spray hose. If for no other reason, you'll never be able to use the hose again.

I am unsure if removing it would cause issue. I'm not brave enough to try.

I have replaced the fittings two of my Delta faucets. One with a diverter. The gaskets were always my issue. You can buy a kit at big box stores that have a complete gasket set to replace them all.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the leak was because of the o-rings